# Magento 2: New custom address fields are shown on checkout, but not saved in DB

Tags: magento, magento2, custom-fields, custom-attributes

I've added 3 custom fields to Magento 2 checkout according to [the official guide from Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html).
*On step 1 I decided to build a Plugin, as recommended.
Now, I can see the new address fields on checkout & I can place an order, but:
1. The custom attributes are missing from the order details (& from DB).
2. On 'My Account', if I want to add new address or edit one, the fields are missing from the address form.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create field in DB table?

Comment: No, I just followed the guide from the docs in hope that Magento have already taken care of that... (as they did with the additional_data for custom payment methods).

Comment: First you have to add your field in customer address then you can set data in it

Comment: Actually, that was my next guess, but it's not written in the guide so I assumed that it should work anyway (See step 4, it's a bit confusing...).
Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Update: I tried that & it still doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @K.Maliszewski, not yet, it's actually on hold at the moment...

Comment: I have the same issue. Please if you found any info, paste it here

Answer (score 1):

Find the following reference links for magento 2 custom filed.

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-field-checkout-address-form-magento2/
```

Comment: I'm familiar with those guides. (*The first one is attached in my question's contents). That's not my issue. I followed the docs & it didn't save the custom fields with the order...